# What C code will determine the network adapter being used by an open socket?

Tags: c++, c, sockets, winapi, network-programming

I have some C code running on MS Windows, which I am compiling/linking with the Microsoft compiler.  The code opens a socket and connects to a remote server.

I want to write some code that determines which Windows network adapter is being used by my open socket.  I can list all the Network adapters in my system using Microsoft's GetAdaptersAddresses function.  In my system there are 12 adapters listed.  I want to write some C code to determine which of those adapters is carrying the traffic for my open socket.

Below is some working sample code, which illustrates a connected socket and enumerating the network adapters.  I have Google-searched for some sample C code to determine which network adapter is associated with my socket, to no avail.  Thanks for any help you can offer.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <Iphlpapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"WS2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"IPHLPAPI.lib")

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static void enumAdapters();

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2,2);
WSADATA wsa;
int sockfd;
struct sockaddr_in addr;

    WSAStartup(ver,&wsa);
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET,"142.250.65.238",&addr.sin_addr) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed inet_pton\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (connect(sockfd,(const struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed connect\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Which of these adapters is my connected socket using?\n\n");
    enumAdapters();
    close(sockfd);
    exit(0);
}


static void enumAdapters()
{
IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES _dummy,*ptr,*buf=&_dummy;
ULONG bufsize=0;

    GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET,0,NULL,buf,&bufsize);
    buf = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *)malloc(bufsize);
    if (GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET,0,NULL,buf,&bufsize) != NO_ERROR) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed to get adapters\n");
        return;
    }
    for (ptr=buf; ptr!=NULL; ptr=ptr->Next) {
        printf("Adapter #%d %s\n",(int)ptr->IfIndex,ptr->AdapterName);
        printf("    %wS (%wS)\n",ptr->FriendlyName,ptr->Description);
    }
    free(buf); 
    return;
}
```

Comment: Generally each individual packet is routed separately. A socket is not associated with an adapter.

Comment: I think `getsockname()` is probably what you want.  You can call to fill out a `sockaddr_in` that will contain the IP address of the NIC that the socket is bound to.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-getsockname

Comment: You can bind a socket for which adapter to listen on, but sent packets go through network routing.

Comment: Thumbing through MSDN's documentation I see that each `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` has a `FirstUnicastAddress`, to a linked list of IP addresses that are assigned to that network interface. I would try my luck at searching it for what I get back with `getsockname` on my socket.

Comment: Another option is to match up the IP from `getsockname()` with the table from `GetIpAddrTable()`, that will give you the index of the network interface being used for that IP. If you need more details, you can match up that index with the `IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES` from `GetAdaptersAddresses()` via its `IfIndex` field

Comment: I actually did try `getsockname()`, hoping that it would have something that I could match against the `FirstUnicastAddress`.  But sadly it did not work out.  The function `getsockname()` returned my public IP address as exposed to the Internet at large, but `FirstUnicastAddress` provides the NAT'ed local IP address.  So I was not able to match anything up.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau I will check out the `GetIpAddrTable()` and see if that provides any useful information that I can use against `FirstUnicastAddress`.

Comment: @stark But the TCP protocol calls `connect()` to a server, so I would think the routing is pretty much permanently established after you call `connect()`.  If the socket were UDP, then I would agree that each packet could be routed through a different adapter.

Comment: @deltamind106 `getsockname()` will return the local IP that the socket is directly bound to. The *only* way it can return your public Internet IP is if your PC is connected directly to your Internet modem. But if it is behind a NAT then `getsockname()` will return the local LAN IP instead. Either way, it *will* match an IP reported by `GetAdaptersAddresses()`. If you are not finding it, then you are probably not iterating through everything correctly. Please update your question to show the latest code you tried that is not working.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau You are correct and `getsockname()` does indeed return the local NAT-ed IP.  I was mistaken earlier when I was testing this in our full application (not the little test program posted here), and it turned out I was looking at the server-side log file for `getpeername()`.  Duh...

Comment: Due to the weak end system model of TCP this is in principle not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution was suggested in the comments of the question by several people, which was to use `getsockname()` to obtain the IP address that the client socket is bound to, and then match that IP address against the `FirstUnicastAddress` from the adapters returned from `GetAdaptersAddresses()`.  Below is the C implementation that works.  The code works with IPv4 only, but it could easily be extended to include IPv6.

Thanks to those who commented in the question to help me solve this.

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <Iphlpapi.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"WS2_32.lib")
#pragma comment(lib,"IPHLPAPI.lib")
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *getAdapterOfSocket(int sockfd,IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES **all_adapters);

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2,2);
WSADATA wsa;
IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *all_adapters=NULL,*adapter=NULL;
char cbuf[48];
struct sockaddr_in addr;
int sockfd;

    WSAStartup(ver,&wsa);
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed socket\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    addr.sin_port = htons(80);
    if (inet_pton(AF_INET,"142.250.65.238",&addr.sin_addr) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed inet_pton\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if (connect(sockfd,(const struct sockaddr *)&addr,sizeof(addr)) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed connect\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    if ((adapter = getAdapterOfSocket(sockfd,&all_adapters)) != NULL) {
        printf("Socket is using adapter index %d\n",adapter->IfIndex);
        printf("    %wS (%wS)\n",adapter->FriendlyName,adapter->Description);
        struct sockaddr_in *sockaddr = (struct sockaddr_in *)adapter->FirstUnicastAddress->Address.lpSockaddr;
        printf("    IP: %s\n",inet_ntop(AF_INET,&sockaddr->sin_addr,cbuf,sizeof(cbuf)));
        printf("    MAC: ");
        for (int n=0; n<adapter->PhysicalAddressLength; n++) {
            printf("%s%02x",n==0?"":"-",(int)adapter->PhysicalAddress[n]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    } else {
        printf("Failed to find adapter used by socket\n");
    }
    if (all_adapters!=NULL) free(all_adapters);
    close(sockfd);
    exit(0);
}


static IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *getAdapterOfSocket(int sockfd,IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES **all_adapters)
{
struct sockaddr_in nameaddr;
int nameaddr_len = sizeof(nameaddr);
IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *ptr;
IP_ADAPTER_UNICAST_ADDRESS_LH *addr;
ULONG bufsize=0;
    
    if (getsockname(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&nameaddr,&nameaddr_len) < 0) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed getsockname\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET,0,NULL,NULL,&bufsize);
    *all_adapters = (IP_ADAPTER_ADDRESSES *)malloc(bufsize);
    if (GetAdaptersAddresses(AF_INET,0,NULL,*all_adapters,&bufsize) != NO_ERROR) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed to get adapters\n");
        return NULL;
    }
    for (ptr=*all_adapters; ptr!=NULL; ptr=ptr->Next) {
        for (addr=ptr->FirstUnicastAddress; addr!=NULL; addr=addr->Next) {
            struct sockaddr_in *sockaddr = (struct sockaddr_in *)addr->Address.lpSockaddr;
            if (memcmp(&sockaddr->sin_addr,&nameaddr.sin_addr,sizeof(struct in_addr)) == 0) {
                return ptr;
            }
        }
    }
    return NULL;
}
```